# Intrinio GetSecurityIntradayPrices example not working - error converting value "iex" to type 'System.Nullable'

Tags: c#, api, exception, error-handling, type-conversion

I tried using Intrinio's example of GetSecurityIntradayPrices but it throws an exception. Here is the link to the code: https://docs.intrinio.com/documentation/csharp/get_security_intraday_prices_v2

I want to mention that other examples/functions work. 
I changed var identifier = "AAPL"; 
Added my sandbox API key.
Tried source as empty string but it requires to to be either "iex" or "bats". 
After I change the source string to "iex" or "bats" it throws the same error. Here is an image with the error: [Error converting value "iex" to type 'System.Nullable'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOBI.png)

Couldn't find anything to solve this problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to version 5.4.0 of Intrinio.SDK seems to solve the problem.